# Running multiple instances of spark-submit from driver

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I have spark running as standalone application on cluster. I submit jobs using "spark-submit" command from driver node (different machine). At a time, only one "spark-submit" job runs. If i execute another, it waits for the previous one to complete. I have opened the ports as required on driver. How can i run multiple instances of "spark-submit" command at a time?

Comment: If you run it on a Hadoop cluster, I would suspect lack of containers. Does the first job consume all of the containers from the cluster? May be first job takes all containers and there are none left on the cluster to initiate an Application Master for the second one.

Comment: Is your cluster YARN, Mesos or Spark standalone?

Comment: @alexeipab - if i run spark-submit job from cluster, i am able to run multiple instances. but in my case, i am running from driver (separate machine).

Comment: @skylerl - I am running spark in standalone mode on port 7077. I am connecting it from driver node using spark-submit and providing necessary arguments.